# What does "navigate the site: mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/navigate?q=navigate

Does it mean "find a good position to place your ad" ?

> Advertisers and sellers often cite a lack of data and tools as challenges in advertising on Amazon, which has given rise to a cottage industry of firms that specialize in helping marketers navigate the site. Meanwhile, Amazon has pushed further into programmatic advertising with its OTT arm that sells ads in some Fire TV apps.

Source: https://www.businessinsider.com/inside-amazons-growing-ad-business-everything-we-know-2019-5

Comment: The relevant definition for **navigate:** ***[intransitive, transitive] (computing)** - (A) to **find your way around** on the internet or on a particular website.* Ex: *Customers will be able to navigate easily throughout the site. (B) to navigate (through) something.* Ex: *Lots of these sites are hard to navigate through.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link does answer your question, if rather vaguely:

> 4) ​[intransitive, transitive] (computing) to find your way around on the internet or on a particular website
>
> *Customers will be able to navigate easily throughout the site.*
>
> **navigate (through) something** *Lots of these sites are hard to navigate through.*

The firms help the marketers find their way around on Amazon, that is, to find the things they need on the site - "a position to place their ad" is one thing they might be looking for, but in the context of the article this might also pertain to various analytics and statistics that are difficult to find.